# How to record remote video in webrtc ios

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, webrtc

I succeeded in playing the remote video on the screen in real time using webrtc-ios and swiftui.
But I also want real-time recording video.
I know how to change the RTCVideooframe to CMsamplebuffer, and I know that I have to save it using Avassetwriter.
But I'm not sure where to extract RTCVideoFrame in real time.

This is my code.

```
struct VideoView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let videoTrack: RTCVideoTrack?
    @Binding var refreshVideoTrack: Bool

    //RTCNSGLVideoView
    //RTCMTLNSVideoView
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> RTCEAGLVideoView {
        let view = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame: .zero)
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: RTCEAGLVideoView, context: Context) {

        if(refreshVideoTrack){
            videoTrack?.add(view)
            refreshVideoTrack = false
        }
    }
} 

VideoView(videoTrack: homeViewModel.remoteVideoTrack, refreshVideoTrack: Binding<Bool>(get: {return homeViewModel.refreshRemoteVideoTrack},
                                                                                                                                                          set: { p in homeViewModel.refreshRemoteVideoTrack = p}))
```

I'm using RTCPeerConnectionDelegate for get remoteVideoTrack

```
func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didAdd stream: RTCMediaStream) {
        dLog("")

        remoteVideoTrack = stream.videoTracks.first
        remoteVideoTrack?.isEnabled = true
        refreshRemoteVideoTrack = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the RTCVideoFrame,you can create an intermediate RTCVideoRenderer

```
class FrameRenderer : NSObject, RTCVideoRenderer {
    func setSize(_ size: CGSize) {}
    func renderFrame(_ frame: RTCVideoFrame?) {}
}
```

```
videoTrack?.add(FrameRenderer())
```